# Как хранить прикрепленные файлы в сообщении?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql-server, база-данных

Есть таблица в базе в которой хранятся сообщения.
id,кому,от кого,тема,текст,дата отправки,статус сообщения
Как реализовать прикрепленные файлы?
Я думал создать поле в котором будут храниться данные в виде json с ссылками на эти файлы.
Но это нарушение первой нормальной формы.Есть еще вариант создать таблицу в которой будет хранится айди сообщения и путь к файлу.Как правильно решить поставленную задачу?Прикрепленные файлы нужно только получать, выборки по ним итд делать не нужно.

Comment: Если выборки по ним не нужны, то храните в JSON'е и не парьтесь - это избавит от лишних JOIN'ов в запросах, а нормализация - не всегда хорошо, в целях увеличения производительности ей можно принебречь

Answer (score 3):

> Есть еще вариант создать таблицу в которой будет хранится айди сообщения и путь к файлу.

ИМХО правильный вариант.